# How to calculate Matrix exponent in Math.net?

Tags: .net, math, matrix

**In Python:**

```
Fnk = np.array([[15.11, 16.11, 17.11, 18.11], [15.11, 16.11, 17.11, 18.11],
                [15.11, 16.11, 17.11, 18.11], [15.11, 16.11, 17.11, 18.11]])

CellPatAm = np.power(10, Fnk / 20)
```

How do I calculate it in math.net? Or what libraries do I use instead?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please edit your post so the code appears correctly (4 spaces at the start of a link of code).

Comment: If you can assume real eigenvalues should be done with `Evd`...according to the docs. Not using .net, though. In other words. The eigenvectors diagonalize the matrix.